# How to use comma separated paths with whitespace as arguments in Bash?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have a dynamic list of paths, each of which may or may not contain whitespace within itself. For example,

```sh
$ STRING='./my text1.txt,./my text2.txt'
```

My ultimate goal is to input those paths as arguments of a command, say `cat`:

```sh
$ cat "./my text1.txt" "./my text2.txt"
cat: ./my text1.txt: No such file or directory  # this is expected!
cat: ./my text2.txt: No such file or directory
```

So I tried:

```sh
$ STRING='./my text1.txt,./my text2.txt'
$ SEP="\"${STRING//,/\" \"}\""
$ echo $SEP
"my text1.txt" "my text2.txt"
$ cat $SEP                          
cat: "my text1.txt" "my text2.txt": No such file or directory
```

In the example above, note that `"my text1.txt" "my text2.txt"` is recognized as a single argument.

My question is, given `STRING`, what do I need to make `cat` recognize `SEP` as two separate arguments?

Thanks.

---

### Context

To give you more information on the context, I'm trying to write a script for Github Actions to integrate [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat) and [changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files/).

```yaml
- name: Get list changed files
  id: changed-files
  uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v17
  with:
    files: |
      **/*.swift

- name: Format Swift code
  run: swiftformat --verbose ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }} --config .swiftformat
```

So I assumed that `STRING` is given and that manually escaping whitespaces (e.g `./my\ text1.txt`) is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your filenames don't have space/glob characters you can use:

```sh
str='./my text1.txt,./my text2.txt'
printf '%s\n' "${str//,/ }" | xargs cat
```

In case your file names can contain whitespaces then use any of these 2 solutions:

```sh
(IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$str"; cat "${arr[@]}")

awk -v ORS='\0' '{gsub(/,/, ORS)} 1' <<< "$str" | xargs -0 cat
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the string on `,` into an array.

```
string='./my text1.txt,./my text2.txt'
IFS=, read -r -a files  <<<"$string"
cat "${files[@]}"
```

or

```
readarray -t -d '' files < <(tr ',' '\0' <<<"$string")
cat "${files[@]}"
```